# Lets Encrypt - Server Error in '/letsencrypt' Application, A Task was Cancelled

Tags: ssl-certificate, azure, lets-encrypt

I have the let's encrypt extension added on Azure through Kudu. This extension has been working fine until recently and now when I try to apply a SSL certificate to a website a get the following error:

> Server Error in '/letsencrypt' Application. A task was canceled.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A
>   task was canceled.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.]
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339641
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.Services.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\Services\BaseHttpAuthorizationChallengeProvider.cs:86
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.Services.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\Services\BaseHttpAuthorizationChallengeProvider.cs:131
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339607
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.Services.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\Services\AcmeService.cs:43
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339607
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.d__13.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\CertificateManager.cs:192
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339607
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.d__14.MoveNext()
>   in D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\CertificateManager.cs:205
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339607
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Controllers.d__7.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\LetsEncrypt-SiteExtension\Controllers\HomeController.cs:229
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +14339607
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +92
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +387    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +188
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +38
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
>   +212    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +166

To try and solve this issue I have upgraded the extension to the latest version, the extension updated but I still got the yellow screen error above.

I have 50 certificates to add to the server and I have tried this in bulk and singularly, every time I make an attempt to add the certificates all 250 websites on the server go down. I am also cautious of the 5 certificate limit that let's encrypt has so I do not want to keep making attempts that fail.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using advice from the following link:

https://www.nuttyabouthosting.co.uk/knowledgebase/article/umbraco-and-lets-encrypt

I had to change the web config from:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
```

to

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/.well-known" />
```

Otherwise Umbraco doesn't route the request correctly.